# NPM error, could not resolve dependency and conflicting peer dependency

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm, dependencies

I have trouble deploying my project on netlify because of NPM errors.

These are my dependencies.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~15.1.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^15.1.2",
    "@angular/common": "~15.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~15.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~15.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~15.1.1",
    "@angular/localize": "~15.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~15.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~15.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~15.1.1",
    "@angular/service-worker": "~15.1.1",
    "@googlemaps/markerclustererplus": "^1.2.3",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "@uiowa/digit-only": "^2.3.0",
    "angular-svg-icon": "^12.0.0",
    "broadcast-channel": "^4.2.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.25.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "ngx-device-detector": "^3.0.0",
    "ngx-image-cropper": "^5.0.1",
    "ngx-progressbar": "^6.1.1",
    "primeflex": "^3.0.1",
    "primeicons": "^4.1.0",
    "primeng": "^12.2.0-rc.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.11.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/jest": "^12.1.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~15.1.2",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "15.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "15.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "15.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "15.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "15.2.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~15.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~15.1.1",
    "@biesbjerg/ngx-translate-extract": "^7.0.4",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.43.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.23",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.172",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "default-passive-events": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.28.0",
    "eslint-plugin-sort-class-members": "^1.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-unused-imports": "^1.1.4",
    "husky": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.7.0",
    "jest": "^27.0.5",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "lint-staged": "^11.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "prettier": "^2.3.1",
    "ts-jest": "^29.0.5",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4"
  }
```

And when doing a simple "npm install" I get this error: 

[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcdPv.png)

I have tried looking around and following many guides but nothing seems to work, for eaxample I have already tried: [These steps](https://www.angularjswiki.com/angular/unable-to-resolve-dependency-tree-error-in-angular-while-installing-npm-packages/) and many other tricks I've found when googling around

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

reinstall node.js: works with at least version v16.18.0
https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.18.0/

and then use `npm i --force`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I still unfortunately get the same error.

Comment: Remove node_modules, package-lock,json and try again.
Then check node and npm versions and post them here

Comment: Did not work either. node v18.13.0 and npm 9.2.0

Comment: have you tried v16.18.0?

Comment: @jonaste were you able to fix this? Have the same error currently

Comment: Sorry, been busy the last couple of days. No I did not try v16.18.0 specifically.
I have found a temporary solution though, the problem for me was that some packages did not work with the latest version of Angular, so I went back to v12 and it worked.

Comment: Same problem here, had a working version with Angular 15.0.4 and cannot upgrade to Angular 15.1.6. I can't tell if this is coming from npm or Angular. And I will not try `--force` because this shouldn't have to be the case with the latest versions of all packages. You'd think the Angular team would have tested it.